# Compare Worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two Worksheets (WS) in one Excel document:

*WS1*

```
FIRST NAME     LAST NAME
```

*WS2*

```
FIRST NAME     LAST NAME     ID
```

I'm looking to add a column in WS1 named MATCHED ID.

MATCHED ID would display (below pseudo code result):

```
(WS1:FIRST NAME + WS1:LAST NAME) COMPARE AGAINST ALL WS2 (WS2:FIRST NAME + WS2:LAST NAME) IF EQUALS (WS1:MATCHED ID).
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried something? Please show us what you received.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to get anything running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column (to the left of your data) on both sheets called `FULL_NAME`, which is `=CONCATENATE(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)`

Then on WS1, `MATCHED ID` is `=VLOOKUP(WS1!FULL_NAME,WS2![RANGE],[ID COLUMN],0)`

Comment: This is the vlookup: =VLOOKUP(WS1!A78,WS2!A2:A5000,MATCHEDID,0) but I keep getting seeing #NAME? in the cell even though I know both Full Names from each worksheet match.

Comment: MatchedID is not a column number, and WS2!A2:A5000 isn't the range you want to use.  Try `=VLOOKUP(WS1!A78,WS2!A2:D5000,4,0)` assuming that FULL NAME is column A and ID is column D on WS2.

Comment: Yap, that did it, needed to expand my Table Array. Thank you!